# amp-mustache template, how can i use it without JSON source external file?

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page, amp-mustache

Can i just define some json inside my **AMP** (accelerated mobile pages) page and use it as amp-mustache source? 
Something like this:

```
<!-- somewhere in header -->
<script async="" custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>

<!-- somewhere in body -->
<script>
var temp = { text : 'some text goes here ... '; },
</script>
<div type="amp-mustache"> <!-- without src="/some/file/with.json" -->
  {{ temp.text }}
</div>
```